# ¿Como solucionar un bucle infinito en una petición GET de una entidad con una relación?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, get

Estoy aprendiendo a usar persistencia con Spring y JPA mientras realizo una API REST, y me ha surgido un problema que no se solucionar a pesar de las búsquedas realizadas aquí y en Google.

El problema es que tengo dos entidades relacionadas con una relación tipo N:M, y al realizar una petición GET de una de ellas me devuelve los atributos de la segunda entidad entre los que se encuentra la lista que hace referencia a la primera entidad, que devuelve la lista de la primera entidad... y así de forma infinita.

He encontrado la anotación `@JsonIgnore` pero eso me genera el problema de que solo muestro todos los datos en una dirección, y necesito ver los datos en las dos direcciones de la relación.

os adjunto el código de las entidades:

**Card.java**

```
@Entity
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    private String quote;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "card_set",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="card_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="set_id", referencedColumnName="acronym"))
    private List<Set> sets;

//GETTERS, SETTERS Y CONSTRUCTORES
}
```

**Set.java**

```
@Entity
public class Set implements Comparable<Set> {
    
    @Id
    @Column(length = 3)
    private String acronym;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sets")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Card> cards;

//GETTERS, SETTERS Y CONSTRUCTORES
}
```

Como veis tengo el `@JsonIgnore` en la entidad Set.

la petición que realizo es la siguiente:
`curl -X GET http: //localhost:8081/mtgdb/card`

Si quito la anotación el resultado es el siguiente:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ad Nauseam",
        "quote": "When the task spilled over into undeath, he stopped calling it his life’s work.",
        "sets": [
            {
                "acronym": "ALA",
                "name": "Shards of Alara",
                "cards": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Ad Nauseam",
                        "quote": "When the task spilled over into undeath, he stopped calling it his life’s work.",
                        "sets": [
                            {
                                "acronym": "ALA",
                                "name": "Shards of Alara",
                                "cards": [
                                    {.....
```

Si agrego el `@JsonIgnore` el resultado en la direccion Card->Set es correcta:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ad Nauseam",
        "quote": "When the task spilled over into undeath, he stopped calling it his life’s work.",
        "sets": [
            {
                "acronym": "ALA",
                "name": "Shards of Alara"
            },
            {
                "acronym": "2XM",
                "name": "Double Masters"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pact of Negation",
        "quote": "Those who expect betrayal at every turn are seldom disappointed.",
        "sets": [
            {
                "acronym": "MMA",
                "name": "Modern Masters"
            },
            {
                "acronym": "FUT",
                "name": "Future Sight"
            }
        ]
    }......
```

Pero para la dirección Set->Card no obtengo que cartas hay en que sets:

```json
[
    {
        "acronym": "ALA",
        "name": "Shards of Alara"
    },
    {
        "acronym": "2XM",
        "name": "Double Masters"
    },
    {
        "acronym": "MMA",
        "name": "Modern Masters"
    },
    {
        "acronym": "MM2",
        "name": "Modern Masters 2015"
    },
......
```

Os dejo también los métodos GET del Controller por si pudiera servir de ayuda:

```
@GetMapping("/set")
public ResponseEntity<?> getSets() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(setRepository.findAll());
}

@GetMapping("/card")
public ResponseEntity<?> getCards() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(cardRepository.findAll());
}
```

Estoy usando:

- Java 15
- Spring Boot 2.3.4
- MySQL como base de datos.

En resumen, necesito poder hacer peticiones GET desde Card hacia Set y viceversa mostrando todos los datos y sin que entre en un bucle infinito. ¿Que recursos tengo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Buenas!Después de días buscando por todos sitios acabo de encontrar una anotación que resuelve el problema de una forma simple.

La anotación `@JsonIgnoreProperties` permite ignorar solo una o varias propiedades de la entidad *(Solo cuando se "parsea" a Json)* cuando se declara con el modificador `value`.

Quedando las entidades así:

```java
@Entity
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    private String quote;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "card_set",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="card_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="set_id", referencedColumnName="acronym"))

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value="cards")
    private List<Set> sets;

//GETTERS, SETTERS Y CONSTRUCTORES
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Set implements Comparable<Set> {
    
    @Id
    @Column(length = 3)
    private String acronym;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sets")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value="sets")
    private List<Card> cards;

//GETTERS, SETTERS Y CONSTRUCTORES
}
```

Cabe destacar que el modificador *value* obtenga varios parámetros se debe usar la siguiente sintaxis: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={"entidad1", "entidad2"}`

Para terminar, al conocer la existencia de esta etiqueta he podido buscar información de forma mas precisa y he encontrado [este enlace de gran utilidad.](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) Ademas de explicar la solución que yo necesito, también te muestra el resto de modificadores existentes.

Un saludo.